# How to delay an image appearing while using a CSS animation on another part

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a web page. In it, I have CSS animations that move images, and when you click on these images, and a larger version of the image with a paragraph shows up in their place. I was trying to have it so the large version of the image and paragraph is delayed, so it shows up after the other images move. I had this working individually, but when I put it together, the large version of the image and paragraph is no longer delayed, and I can't figure out why. Here is my code:    https://jsfiddle.net/rfradkin/eq2h50kg/1/

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 10000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("yeep");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
  document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate')
  document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate')
  document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate')
  document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate');

}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:20px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.yeep1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.yeep2 {
  color: purple;
}

.yeep3 {
  color: green;
}
.yeep4 {
  color: blue;
}

.yeep1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
#column1 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- I'm trying to have the images move to the bottom using a CSS animation after they are clicked. After I do this by adding the code that works for this, the function you wrote stopped working. I can't figure out why. Can you help me?-->



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body class='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep1'> Parapraph #1 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="myFunction(this);">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please take a look. I'm new to programming and any help I can get would be useful. Thanks and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Think of it async,  each setTimeout gets run immediately, then waits, and they all execute at basically the same time after each timeout expires.   You want to use async/await or .then to solve this problem.   I'll go fork your fiddle and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm looking forward to seeing what you come up with :)

Comment: Did you tried with animate-delay? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay if at the beginning is visible, you can set in the animation 0% opacity:0;

Comment: I'm working on it as we speak

Comment: The problem I am having is I am not trying to delay the animation of the images moving, I'm trying to delay the new image and paragraph showing up (which isn't an animation)

Comment: @BrianPatterson do you have any updates?

Comment: @rf19 Still working on it but basically using a callback with addEventListener.   I have it waiting the correct time, just resolving some scoping issues etc.. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so quick explanation of this code ... we have the onclick of the HTML elements calling the function `handleClick` and passing it `this` aka the img that was clicked.

Inside our handler we grab the source of the image from the src attribute, and the p element that is contained in the `yeep` attribute.   Then we loop through each column setting the animations in motion, and when we get to the final column we create a variable for the animation and add an event handler with a callback (which needed to be wrapped in an anonymous function or it wouldn't work correctly).   We pass the callback our column4 (or last) element along with the src and yeep attribute contents as parameters.

Once our animations finish, our callback fires, which then sets the larger image source and the paragraph contents to their respective elements, and then sets their displays to make them visible.

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 10000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}

function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var t,
      el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var animations = {
    "animation"      : "animationend",
    "OAnimation"     : "oAnimationEnd",
    "MozAnimation"   : "animationend",
    "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
  }

  for (t in animations){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}

const customCallback = (e, s, y) => {
  let p = document.getElementById("img-paragraph");
  p.innerHTML = y;
  var expImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  expImg.src = s;
  expImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  p.style.display = "table-cell";
  let ele = document.getElementById("column4");
  ele.removeEventListener(window.animationEvent, customCallback);
}

const handleClick = (e) => {
  let yeep = e.getAttribute("yeep");
  let eleArr = ["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"];
  for (ele in eleArr) {
    let thisEle = document.getElementById(eleArr[ele]);
    if (thisEle.classList) thisEle.classList.add('animate')
      else thisEle.className += " " + "animate";
    if (eleArr[ele] === "column4") {
      var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent();
      thisEle.addEventListener(animationEvent, () => customCallback(thisEle, e.src, yeep));
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:20px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.yeep1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.yeep2 {
  color: purple;
}

.yeep3 {
  color: green;
}
.yeep4 {
  color: blue;
}

.yeep1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
#column1 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: relative;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: floatBubble 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
  }
}
@keyframes floatBubble {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      top: 500px;
      left:50px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- I'm trying to have the images move to the bottom using a CSS animation after they are clicked. After I do this by adding the code that works for this, the function you wrote stopped working. I can't figure out why. Can you help me?-->



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body class='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep1'> Parapraph #1 </p>" onclick="handleClick(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
        alt="Snow" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="handleClick(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="handleClick(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" yeep="<p class='yeep4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="handleClick(this);">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @rf19 I was able to get the image working, but need to get the paragraph text working.   I have to go to a meeting now though, so I will be back in a couple hours and finish it up.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @rf19 OK, updated my answer with the working code snippet.  Please give it a try.

Comment: Looks great! Thank you so much